# posts_per_page and offset aren't working. Whats wrong?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, args

So I'm using the following piece of code:

```
<?php 
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>4, 'offset'=>1);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
endwhile;endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

But it seems like my arrays are being completely ignored. What's wrong?

Comment: You need to loop over the variable `$the_query` to fetch the posts, you are using the global function, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using in ajax you can try add `post_status => "publish"` to query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$the_query = get_posts( $args );
```

It should work and use `foreach` instead of `while`.
This should solve your problem.